# Raspberry PI 3 connection to local host refused

Tags: raspberry-pi, localhost

I am aware there are multiple topics about this, but i'm a total linux noob and i can't seem to figure it out. I downloaded the unifi controller application on my raspberry. This uses your localhost ip addr and port 8443. But when i try to connect it refuses my connection. Before my raspberry crashed(unfortunate) i installed the app and it was running properly right away (probably got something to do with OS updates that i skipped for about 2 years). Do you have any ideas?

(no firewalls in my LAN present)

lo adapter info:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 106  bytes 6492 (6.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 106  bytes 6492 (6.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: If this application is trying to connect to some port on localhost there must be something that is listening on that port. If you `Connection refused` it means that nothing is listening. Show output of `sudo lsof -i:8443`.

Comment: I have tried this, but unfortunately it still displays a warning that localhost refused to connect.